# Binding CheckBox IsChecked value to a Property

Tags: wpf, xaml, checkbox, binding

I have a `ListView` where each Item is a `CheckBox` followed by the `Name`property.

```
  <ListView Name="ShapesList"
           SelectionChanged="ShapesList_OnSelectionChanged"
           Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"
           ItemsSource="{Binding ChartViewModel.OidList}"
           Margin="15,0,10,10"
           SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Style="{DynamicResource BigCheckbox}"
                                        IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected3, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                        Content="{Binding Path=Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"
                                         Checked="RoiChecked" Unchecked="RoiUnchecked"/>
                         </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="ROI" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"  />
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
```

Where `IsSelected3` is a Property of a Class that inherits `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
 public bool IsSelected3
 {
     get { return _isSelected3; }
     set
     {
         _isSelected3 = value;
         FirePropertyChanged("IsSelected3");
     }
  }
```

The problem is that the `IsChecked` binding doesn't work, instead the one with Name does.

Do you have any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Which class is it a property of? If it's a property of the things contained in ChartViewModel.OldList, just use `IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected3}"`. Is your `Name` binding working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the idea given by Kyle I found the solution:

```
IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=DataContext.IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

If the `x:Type` is `ListViewItem` it works.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Two changes:

```
Path=DataContext.IsSelected3
x:Type ListView
```

IsChecked binding now looks like:

```
IsChecked="{Binding Path=DataContext.IsSelected3, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle, but unfortunately it still doesn't work.